# how to rotate image image 3d in jquery on swipe up and swipe down

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I have to rotate my image in 3d as shown in below image .There is **blue** line .I need to rotate my image in this  direction when swipe up and down .please ignore **green** green line
is there any way when I swipe up or swipe down it spin / rotate some angle ..

here is my fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/wemsbtwj/2/

```
function scrolling() {
    $("img").css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + ($("main").scrollTop() / mainHeight * 360) + 'deg)'
    });
}

var mainHeight = $("main").height();

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrolling, false);
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is very wrong.. first: 'main' is not a valid HTML element, second: your fiddle doesn't have jquery attached, third: you won't catch the window scroll event unless there's something to scroll... fourth: I hope you don't expect to rotate that tire as if rotating a car wheel naturally, it's not going to do that.. to get a feel for rotate --> http://jsfiddle.net/wemsbtwj/4/ (you'll have to resize the result window until you get a vertical scroll to see it)

Comment: sorry i done lot of mistake..But I saw lot of example on website to scoll like that. how I will achieve this.I will give example if you see datepicker spinner it also roate like that .may I use animation

Comment: actually i need it show spin about it axis when I swipe up and swipe down

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean.. do you have a link to an example of what you want?

Comment: can we scroll like that ...I download that example http://plnkr.co/edit/7OEayuXqNP8NBECdJPhJ?p=preview which have scrolling